# How to get current date minimum datetime values in a table one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want get staff attendance records. office employees work started time and end time wise gathering record. Using SQL server DB, in table one field, here not using strat_time and end_time two fields. Easily get maximum date values, but minimum value get old date rather then today dates, as per SQL server query below:

```
SELECT  Sy.SystemUserName,
        MIN(Sc.CreatedOn) as StartedTime,   
        MAX(Sc.CreatedOn) as ExitTime,
        datediff(MINUTE, MIN(Sc.CreatedOn) , MAX(Sc.CreatedOn)) as WorkingHours  
from gunageorge.SystemDetails Sy   
LEFT JOIN gunageorge.Screenshots Sc on Sy.id = Sc.SystemId   
where Sy.CompanyGUID =  '25' AND  Sy.IsDeleted = 0
GROUP By Sy.SystemUserName
```

Where condition only that date value only returned, null value not returning.

Returned values like that

| Name | Starttime | EndTime | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ray | 2021-11-23 06:01:42.2300045 | 2022-03-14 09:19:44.9513129 | 160038 |
| vijay | 2022-03-14 04:09:49.4479046 | 2022-03-14 07:34:47.8999912 | 205 |
| Parthi | 2022-02-02 08:26:11.2394531 | 2022-03-14 09:19:47.1416970 | 57653 |
| Sugu | 2022-02-01 09:17:22.3333451 | 2022-03-14 09:19:07.0365219 | 59042 |
| Uday | NULL | NULL | NULL |

Here I want started date is today's started time only. Don't old records. Also want NULL records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get to check that there are 0 days between today, using `getdate()`, and CreatedOn

```
WHERE datediff(dd,Sc.CreatedOn,getdate()) = 0
```

so the query becomes

```
SELECT  Sy.SystemUserName,
        MIN(Sc.CreatedOn) as StartedTime,   
        MAX(Sc.CreatedOn) as ExitTime,
        datediff(MINUTE, 
        MIN(Sc.CreatedOn) , 
        MAX(Sc.CreatedOn)) as WorkingHours  
from gunageorge.SystemDetails Sy   
LEFT JOIN gunageorge.Screenshots Sc on Sy.id = Sc.SystemId   
where Sy.CompanyGUID =  '25' 
AND  Sy.IsDeleted = 0
and (datediff(dd,Sc.CreatedOn,getdate()) = 0
Or SC.CreatedOn IS NULL) 
GROUP By Sy.SystemUserName
```

Comment: Yes, Its working. but when Sc.CreatedOn field value null then Sy.SystemUserName did now return value. if Sc.CreatedOn value null means return AB Other wise return date duration. Please suggest me

Comment: I've modified the where. Please test the new version. Thank you

Comment: its working. if any one systemusername have no startdate and end date then did not show systemusername also. i want system username if no date means. Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: You'll have to post your table definitions and some sample data.

Comment: For example above my question table data, if second row vijay system name have no startdatetime and enddatetime then you given query not show that name in returned list. i want if no startdatetime and enddatetime means just show 1990-01-01 this only and duration 0

Comment: Name           |     StartTime                 |     EndTime                   |    Duration
---------------|-------------------------------|-------------------------------|-----------------
Ray            | 2021-11-23 06:01:42.2300045   |  2022-03-14 10:04:45.4331689  |   160083        
vijay          |  1990-01-01        |             1990-01-01        |   0                       if no date means return like this.

Comment: Sir, above the example top table data, five members data available. In this list of member, next day some one data null or not exit then that member name did not return in this query. now data exit members only show. need to all members name and date exit then calculate duration time otherwise 'AB' or old date '1990-01-01'. Please suggest me.

Comment: Please add sample lines and table definition to question or give a DBfiddle link.

Comment: TN : gunageorge.SystemDetails :
Id int,
CreatedOn datetime2,
CreatedBy nvarchar,
ModifiedOn datetime2,
ModifiedBy nvarchar,
isActivated nvarchar,
DeletedOn datetime2,
DeletedBy nvarchar,
IsDeleted bit,
GuidID nvarchar,
SystemIP nvarchar,
SystemUserName nvarchar,
SystemOS nvarchar,
CompanyGUID nvarchar,
TeamId int
TN : gunageorge.Screenshots :
Id int,
CreatedOn datetime2,
CreatedBy nvarchar,
ModifiedOn datetime2,
ModifiedBy nvarchar,
isActivated nvarchar,
DeletedOn datetime2,
DeletedBy nvarchar,
IsDeleted bit,
GuidId nvarchar,
SystemId int,
Screenshotname nvarchar